# Show/hide controls before rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, user-interface

I've got a layout working using a UISplitViewController, with some custom controls at the bottom of each pane. When I rotate the view to portrait mode, I want to hide the master view controls while it's in popover mode. This part works fine.

Here's the code:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
            _refreshButton.hidden = NO;
            _aboutButton.hidden = NO;
            _bottomBar.hidden = NO;
        }
        if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
            _refreshButton.hidden = YES;
            _aboutButton.hidden = YES;
            _bottomBar.hidden = YES;
        }
    }   
}
```

The problem is when I rotate back to landscape mode. The controls reappear, but only after the rotation is complete. It's functional, but ugly. Is there a way to force them to redraw before the rotation actually occurs?

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but have you tried moving the call to the super-implementation below your hiding/showing code?

Comment: @Till: Good idea, but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with Apple build-in animations is that they will block whatever else is going on while they are preforming. This particularly happens when you want to display a preloader while you do some pretty magic with your interface. The way to go about it is to do your own GUI management on a different thread:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(showHideMenu) withObject:nil];
```

or if possible deleying the animation task untill you do what you want

```
[self showHideMenu];
[self performSelector:@selector(doRotation) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
```

Comment: The first option (once I worked out how to do it) had the effect of the controls disappearing before rotating to portrait view as well as reappearing after rotating back to landscape. I didn't really want to try to monkey with doing my own view rotation, so I gave the second option a pass. What I ended up doing for now was fixing the distance of the controls from the top of the view and making the popover short enough that they're not shown in portrait view. Not very elegant code-wise, but looks better from the user's perspective.